# Regex: remove everything but a certain string from a big string?

Tags: regex, replace

I have this string: *this is my big string*

I want to remove everything except "this is my" from that string. The part that has to be removed differs, only the first part (this is my) stays the same. How can I do that using a regex?

Thanks!

Comment: What tool are you going to use? Sed, perl, grep, java, ...?

Comment: why would you need to use regexes, when what stays in the string always is the same anyway?

Comment: JavaScript, but I tried in PHP and [^this is my].* seems to be working, not sure if it covers all cases.

Comment: If you know what you are keeping, then why not just ignore the "big string" and set the result to the (known) target string?

Comment: You should edit you question to include javascript, since the question is "more" javascript oriented than regex oriented.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the string you want to have in your variable, simply assign it.

There is no need to use regex'es (as in, it doesn't make sense) for the case you describe.